# Retornar nomes dos items selecionados de uma checkboxTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Como posso verificar quais são os items selecionados de uma `checkboxTree` ?

Já tive a pesquisar e sei que este código retorna o ultimo selecionado:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) checkboxTree1.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
```

Existe alguma forma de saber os nomes dos nodes das checkboxes selecionadas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso algo que me retorne "Colors, blue , red".

Answer (score 1):

O `node` possui um método [`getUserObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/MutableTreeNode.html) que retorna o objeto referente ao nó atual (e.g., se você alimentou a árvore com a string `"red"` basta converter o `Object` para uma `String`):

```
String color = (String) node.getUserObject();
```

Para buscar todos os caminhos selecionados você pode usar:

```
TreePath[] paths = checkboxTree1.getSelectionPaths();
```

Por sua vez cada `TreePath` também possui o método `getLastPathComponent()`:

```
if (paths != null) {
    for (TreePath path : paths) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
        System.out.println(node.getUserObject());
    }
}
```

Se você quiser também os parentes (não sei se é o caso) pode utilizar ainda o método [`getPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getPath--) que retorna um `Object[]` com todos os elementos desde a raiz.

Comment: Quando se refere a todos os caminhos selecionados, está a referir-se aos items selecionados ?

Comment: Caminho implica tudo (desde a raiz). Por exemplo, o caminho de "blue" seria `JTree -> colors -> blue`, o `lastPathComponent`desse caminho seria `blue`.